# C# WPF mysql string

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, string

I'm creating a wpf app that is connected to localhost database, it has 2 tables, now I ran into an error but I'm not sure what is wrong in the code. Can anyone help?

**I'm getting this error:**

> An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException'
>   occurred in MySql.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'left join author on
>   book.author_id=author.id' at line 1

```
private void Filter_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        connection.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();  

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM book where book.name like ('" + Filter.Text + "%') left join author on book.author_id=author.id";   

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        _dataView = new System.Data.DataView(dt);
        _dataView.Sort = "name ASC,id ASC";
        BooksGrid.DataContext = dt;
        connection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: What error gives your query in your database manager? Looks like it is not a valid sql. Have you ever tried it without `(` and `)`? And you don't need `ExecuteNonQuery` line. Don't forget to use `using` statement to dispose your connection, command and adapter automatically instead of calling `Close` method manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM book left join author on book.author_id=author.id where book.name like ('" + Filter.Text + "%') and book.author_id=author.id";
```

The additional "book.author_id=author.id" clause at the end is to ensure that you only get records that match on author_id.

Also instead of cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(), you should try and use the cmd.ExecuteReader() since you are retrieving rows.